# Can a custom field be populated by external JSON?

Tags: custom-fields, json

I'm building the marketing portion of a larger system, where a catalog of products is in a separate database. I need a custom `select` field that represents the products in the catalog, so I can relate products to blog posts. How can I populate this field via JSON, in real (or near-real) time? Has anyone done this before?

All I need to store is an ID in EE, which I can later use to pull in the full details of the product on demand so what's displayed is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (ie. cheapest) is to not re-invent the wheel and use an EE addon to do it for you, we have used DataGrab (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) to do something similar, it may work for you - give it a look.

Comment: Not re-inventing the wheel is exactly why I posted the question :)

Comment: How would you use DataGrab in this instance? I've used it on other projects to import custom data sets into channel entries, but how would you see it helping me populate a field as I describe?

Comment: I had assumed when you said all you needed to do was store an ID in EE I assumed you ment in a channel (ie. the product cat ID in the entry), obviously this is not a problem for datagrab. If you mean you want to populate the select dynamically via javascript that would be different.
So basically I'm not fully understanding what you are attempting to do, maybe you could be a bit more specific?

Comment: Right, the value I store doesn't need to be dynamic, but the options in the dropdown need to be dynamically generated.

Comment: I basically have two sites; Site A manages a list of categories for both sites. I need a custom field for Site B that shows the categories as provided by Site A in real time.

Comment: there are multiple ways I can think of to do this, however, I still need more clarity to suggest one. Why do you need a custom field in a channel for Site B to show the categories in Site A? The reason I ask is because if you're talking about the select being populated and shown on the frontend it wouldn't be necessary - you would handle it in template code - not in channel data. If however, you actually need the field to be populated dynamically in a channel entry for selection when creating an entry in the channel that would be different - and bring up even more questions.

Comment: For example if you had a field that was dynamic in the channel when making the entry, once something was selected out of it how are you going to handle the entry when the data changes? Ie. the cat you selected for the entry might not even be available or different after it changes on Site A. It sounds like if you really need this to be dynamic in close to real time (because if not datagrab can still do it for a field in Site A to a field in Site B [or cat]) you shouldn't be using a channel dynamic field - you should be doing it on the frontend.

Comment: Oh, i should mention a simple way to do it using javascript. The fixed ID you store in the Site B entry would be used in a javascript ajax call that would send the ID to Site A, which would then respond with a JSON response containing the data needed to populate the select. Of course this is making the big assumption that you have a fixed ID you can use on Site A that can be used to relate it in Site B. Something needs to be "fixed" if you're going to do any type of relationship.

Comment: You could also do the same thing in template code using curl (which is a bit more secure and avoids XSS stuff). The call would be made by the template and rendered thru to the frontend - no javascript necessary.